# Trying to get timing for a C function leads to system halted

Tags: c, gcc, clock, timing

I am trying to get timing for a C function on Ubuntu. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>   

int main(){
clock_t start1, end1;
int ITER = 250;
uint32_t i = 0;

uint32_t a[16] = {0x000000f0,0x000ff000, 0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00ff0000, 0x000f0000, 0x00fa0000, 0x00eee000,0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000};
uint32_t b[16] = {0x00000fff,0xff000000, 0x0ff00000,0x00ff0000,0x000ff000, 0x0000ff00, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000};
uint32_t m[16] = {0x00000fff,0xff000000, 0x0ff00000,0x00ff0000,0x000ff000, 0x0000ff00, 0x00000ff0, 0x000000ff,0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000};


uint32_t res[16] = {0};

start1 = clock();
for(i = 0; i < ITER; i +=1){
        Myfunction(res, b, a, m);
}
end1 = clock();
printf("clock_per_sec = %.8f\n",(float)(end1 - start1)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC * ITER));
return 0;
}
```

If I set the `ITER` variable to 250, I'd get my timing around 2~9 us. So, I tried to set the `ITER` variable to some greater number like 1000 to get more accurate timing values. However, even for `ITER = 251` when I run my code, I've got system halted. I cannot figure out where the problem is, since my function takes around 5 us in average, running 1000 times should take around 5 ms. My function is an inline assembly function which uses AArch64 advanced SIMD assembly instructions and vector registers. Could it be related to that?

Comment: Your problem is likely due to problems in `Myfunction` or your `float` cast. Try casting to `(double)` and change the format specifier to `%.8lf`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I changed it as you mentioned, but nothing have been changed. I am still getting system halted